# MySQL SELECT GROUP_CONCAT and use it in a WHERE clause in another select

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

I have two tables. One that contains `account` settings and one temporary `options`.

**The settings table**

```
--------------------------
id   account    category
--------------------------
1    account 1   main
2    account 2   main
3    account 3   general
4    account 4   main
--------------------------
```

**Then I have options**

```
--------------------------
id   account    option
--------------------------
1    account 1   select
2    account 2   none
--------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is to have only the `accounts` which `category` is `main` and `option` is not `select` but also exists in the first table.

so in the example data above the result should be `account 2` and `account 4`

I have tried to `GROUP_CONCAT` the accounts from table accounts and then to check if any of the accounts are in the `concated list`.

But didn't work. It says Unknown column ConAccounts
Maybe I should use `WHERE EXISTS`?
Sorry I am not very good this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.account) 
FROM settings s
WHERE s.category = 'main'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM options o
    WHERE o.account = s.account AND o.option = 'select'
  )
```

Comment: Yes, That is what I was looking for. Thanks